# Formatting while statement (or for, ...) with indent

Tags: format, code

Can GNU indent be made to format a while (or for, ...) statement to a single line?

My indent (GNU indent 2.2.11) outputs this

```
while (a == b)
    b++;
```

I'd like it to output one single line instead. I tried a lot of the options but haven't been able to come up with the right combination (it it's at all possible) yet.

```
while (a == b) b++;
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) arr[i] = i;
```

Answer (score 2):

I can't do it using `indent` but using [`uncrustify`](http://uncrustify.sourceforge.net/). With:

```
uncrustify --show-config
```

you can see its configuration options, then you have to create the file `~/.uncrustify.cfg` where you'll define your style. For what concerns your issue you must put in your configuration file:

```
nl_create_if_one_liner    True
nl_create_for_one_liner   True
nl_create_while_one_liner True
```

See `man uncrustify` to learn how to invoke `uncrustify`.

Comment: +1 Thank you cYrus. I've installed uncrustify and played a bit with it. I'll be testing it more deeply in the coming days.